# How to add button in mail body in MFMailComposeViewController in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-simulator

I want to create a button in body of mail using MFMailComposeViewController.When click on button it will open a window in browser.

```
 NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
    // add HTML before the link here with line breaks (\n)
    [body appendString:@"<h1>Hello User!</h1>\n"];

    [body appendString:@"<form><input type=\"button\" value=\"Open Window\"onclick=\"window.open('someurl')\"></form>"];
    [body appendString:@"<div>Thanks much!</div>\n"];

    [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
```

I wrote the code for button creation in mail.But what i need is When click on button i have open a window in browser.

Comment: what is the result of above code?

Comment: when i sent mail to my email.I got mail with button.But when click on button no action is happened.

Comment: You're trying to put javascript in an email. This is not allowed! You need to make the button a standard link (styled as a button)

Comment: Please Can u suggest me how to do it?

Comment: have a look at this http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/43727-adding-link-in-the-email-message.html

Comment: i need like a button format